# forma correcta de inicio de sesión en java

Tags: java, mysql

no estoy seguro de si es la forma correcta de iniciar la sesión en una aplicación en java.

En mi proyecto lo único que hago es una comprobación de usuario y contraseña en la base de datos, si el usuario y contraseña es correcto abro el JDesktopPane con los datos del usuario logrado incluyendo el ID, el id me sirve para realizar operaciones posteriores con los demás formularios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después para cerrar la sesión lo único que hago es cerrar el formulario principal con un this.dispose();

adjunto mi archivo de conexión;

```
public class conexion {
public String db ="Juntaagua";
public String url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:8889/"+db;
public String user="root";
public String pass= "root";
public int nombre = 1;

public conexion() {
}

public Connection conectar(){
Connection link = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
        link=DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, this.user, this.pass);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, e);
    }

return link;
}
```

}

espero su respuesta gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Para el desarrollo del inicio de sesión de tu aplicación puedo darte dos consejos:

1. Utiliza un PreparedStatement para realizar la consulta que verifique la existencia del usuario en tu base de datos, para evitar inyecciones sql, podes chequear como se hace acá http://www.javamexico.org/blogs/ezamudio/ejemplo_de_inyeccion_de_sql .
2. Nunca muestres el id del usuario, debe ser transparente para quien utiliza la aplicación, usalo internamente para las operaciones que necesites pero no se lo muestres ni pidas, es un número que no tiene por que importarle y mucho menos memorizar.

Comment: estimado amigo muchas gracias por sus consejos ya incorpore el PreparedStament, pero entonces la forma que hago el inicio y cierre de sección es correcta?, es la forma que normalmente se hace o como lo haría usted saludos.

Comment: De hecho si, para un caso simple de inicio de sesión en aplicaciones de escritorio lo que se suele hacer es una consulta en la tabla de usuarios para ver si existe alguno con el nombre y la contraseña ingresada.